# Show hide not working when add a wrap for text inside li

Tags: jquery

The following works to show / hide content when i click the li, but when i wrap the text with `<a></a>` , then update the script , it no longer works , here are my 2 example of working and not working

Working

```
   <ul class="tabbed-reports">
    <li class="report1 current">Chat</li>
    <li class="report2">Tweets</li>
    <li class="report3">Activity</li>
    <li class="report4">Options</li>
    <li class="report5">Notes</li>
   </ul>

   <div class="reports-content">
    <div class="report1">REPORT 1</div>
    <div class="report2" style="display:none;">REPORT 2</div>
    <div class="report3" style="display:none;">REPORT 3</div>
    <div class="report4" style="display:none;">REPORT 4</div>
    <div class="report5" style="display:none;">REPORT 5</div>
   </div>


<script>
$('.tabbed-reports li').on('click',function(e){
    $('.reports-content>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});

var selector = '.tabbed-reports li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

But if i wrap the li in an a tag , and revise the script , it will no longer work , what have i done wrong here?

```
   <ul class="tabbed-reports">
    <li class="report1 current"><a>Chat</a></li>
    <li class="report2"><a>Tweets</a></li>
    <li class="report3"><a>Activity</a></li>
    <li class="report4"><a>Options</a></li>
    <li class="report5"><a>Notes</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="reports-content">
    <div class="report1">REPORT 1</div>
    <div class="report2" style="display:none;">REPORT 2</div>
    <div class="report3" style="display:none;">REPORT 3</div>
    <div class="report4" style="display:none;">REPORT 4</div>
    <div class="report5" style="display:none;">REPORT 5</div>
   </div>


<script>
$('.tabbed-reports li a').on('click',function(e){
    $('.reports-content>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});

var selector = '.tabbed-reports li a';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('li a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: `it will no longer work` what is not working can you provide sample snippet?

Comment: will no longer  show / hide the reports-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `e.target.classList[0]` is empty because click event is bound to the `<a>` elements and it doesn't has any class.

If you want that HTML structure you must set `class="report1"` and other classes to `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$(selector).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings('.active,.current')
                                       .removeClass('active current');
});
```

First you go to the upper level (`LI`) and add `active` class to it. Then, selecting its siblings with classes `active` and `current`, and remove those classes from the matched elements.

Note that I also added `e.preventDefault()` to prevent and redirect action when you click on the `A` element.

Answer (score 1):

It will not longer work because in the second code you have

```
$('.tabbed-reports li a').on('click',function(e){
    $('.reports-content>.'+ 
    e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

But e.target.classList[0] points not to

```
li
```

but to

```
a
```

tag, which doesn't have any class.Try to replace it with

```
$('.tabbed-reports li a').on('click',function(e){
    $('.reports-content>.'+ 
    e.target.parentElement.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: this is what i was missing , needed to define a class , ty for the catch !